# Formatting text in the model with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I make this MVC?

```
  class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :price, :presence => true

    def to_s
      "#{name} at #{number_to_currency(price)}"
    end

  end
```

I need to format price to a currency, but I can't use number_to_currency, because this is in the model.  I could pass the view into this, but that doesn't feel very clean.

Comment: Does it need to be in the model? Where and how do you use this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be to define a `ProductHelper` module in `app/helpers` that implements the method you want, say `product_name_with_price`:

```
module ProductHelper
  def product_name_with_price(product)
    "#{product.name} at #{number_to_currency(product.price)}"
  end
end
```

and then in the view

```
<%= product_name_with_price(@product) %>
```

Comment: I am using the .to_s in other models though (specifically to generate PDFs)  So technically this never sees a view.

Comment: Well, if you ask how to make this M **V** C I suppose there's must be some kind of view. How do you generate the PDF?

Comment: I am using Prawn and the pdfs are getting sent out via email.  So the client doesn't see them in the view.

Comment: Can you update your question adding the code you use to generate the pdf?

Answer (score 1):

It is a violation of MVC, but you can have `number_to_currency` in the model if you wish. You just need to include `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper`.

```
  class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
    validates :price, :presence => true

    def to_s
      "#{name} at #{number_to_currency(price)}"
    end

  end
```